# Popstate history and link

Tags: javascript

i have problem with this function if i click in a simple link this function is call but i need to call him just for previous/next button in navigator or button in keyboard

```
$(window).on("popstate", function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the onbeforeunload event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
}
```

Demo here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm